# How do I get the guild.id from the server when the bot joins discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

as the caption says I don't know how I get the guild.id from a server when the bot just joined.
I need the guild.id inside the guildCreate event.

EDIT:
My problem was a misspell in my code that didn't got tagged as an error.
Because I need the guild.id for a database entry I'm using MySQL and I was missing a "`". Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the `guild` as a parameter to guildCreate:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  const { id } = guild;
  // do something with id
});
```

Comment: you have variable name mismatch from g -> guild in the function

Comment: Hey,
thanks for the quick answer, I had it the whole time right in my code but made a misspell for a databse entry. Thanks anyways

Comment: @emirate. Because this answered your actual question that you asked, could you please mark it as the accepted answer?